# How to format a date as a string instead of an object with 3 values

Tags: json, spring, swagger, openapi

I have defined the openapi/swagger definition like follows in a yaml file:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info: { title: "", description: "", version:  ""}
tags:
  - name: DateValue
paths:
  /dateValue:
    get:
      tags:
        - DateValue
      summary: GET Date Informations
      operationId: getDateValue
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: id
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/DateResponse'
components:
  schemas:
    DateResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        Id:
          type: string
          description: The id
        DateValue:
          type: string
          format: date
          description: The date
```

For some reason the response looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": "12345",
    "DateValue": [
        2022,
        8,
        9
    ]
}
```

The property in the generated class looks like this so I've assumed it should use the correct pattern:

```
  @JsonProperty("DateValue")
  @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso = org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
  private LocalDate dateValue;
```

Do I need to do anything else to get the correct pattern for a Date? It should look like this: "yyyy-MM-dd"
And not an object with 3 values as a list.

I've tried to add the pattern manually by myself to the yaml definitin like so:

```
       DateValue:
          type: string
          format: date
          description: The date
          pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

But this didn't change anything.